# iOS Newsstand download failed when shut down the app

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I'm having difficulty in the download using NewsstandKit when the app shut down.

My newsstand app download does starts in Background Mode, and exit to the background or push a download notification, the download issue everything is OK, but i shut down the app then the task is downloading，the downloading task failed.

Does it has to do some thing with the Server? or others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resume your downloads when the App Launches again.

Something to the tune of this would work

```
// Inside App Delegate Did Finish Launching
NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];

for(NKAssetDownload *asset in [nkLib downloadingAssets]){
    [asset downloadWithDelegate:newsstandDownloadDelegate];
}
```

If you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html) you will find the following paragraph detailing how you should handle app termination:

> While assets are being downloaded, the application could be suspended
>   or even terminated entirely if, for instance, there is insufficient
>   memory or the user force-quits the application. The application
>   (assuming it has the newsstand-content property) is later relaunched
>   into the background to handle the completion of the download or any
>   authentication challenges or errors related to it. The procedure in
>   this case is the following:
>
> When the application is launched, it can use the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey key to access an array
>   in the launchOptions dictionary passed into the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. If there is an array, it
>   contains the identifiers that caused the launch; these could be
>   identifiers for downloads that have finished downloading that or could
>   not complete downloading. It iterates through the array of
>   NKAssetDownload objects from the downloadingAssets property of the
>   NKLibrary object and calls downloadWithDelegate: on each of them. If
>   it wants, the application can use the asset identifiers obtained in
>   the previous step to check which asset downloads caused the relaunch.
>   The NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate object handles the asset downloads
>   as it does normally. The Newsstand Kit framework expects all calls of
>   its methods to be made on the main thread; the NSURLConnectionDelegate
>   Protocol methods are also invoked on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i see the document and resume NKLibrary problem,  about resume my download is ok, my problem is when i 'shut down' the app, the downloading disconnected，why?

Comment: NSURLRequest *req = MyURLRequest;
NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:issueID];
NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:req];    self.downloadConnect = [asset downloadWithDelegate:self];

Comment: Have you added the newsstand key to your app plist? Ie does your app actually appear in the newsstand shelf?

Comment: How exactly are you tracking the download to determine that it has stopped?

Comment: Yes,plist setting is OK, appeared in newsstand.>I connected issue download url for zip file, start to downloading, through expectedTotalBytes xx% percent exactly, and i shut down then app in the background, then the connecting downloading failed.

Comment: If you are using your XCode terminal to debug then that's the issue. The download will continue through newsstand and not your app. You must use Charles or a web proxy to monitor the download. So once your app terminates newsstand will finish the download and relaunch your app in the background to handle the completion

Comment: O, 'You must use Charles or a web proxy to monitor the download', I also consider the problem may be server setting, tks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your server since you have already initiated the request and that works fine

Comment: ......except shut down the background program downloading failed, everything is OK, so i have to re-check others.

Comment: But you are saying downloading failed because you aren't seeing log messages? Try and set the newsstand badge number when the download code gets triggered in the background. That way you will know for sure

Comment: Yes, newsstand badge and changed icon is must be required for newsstand app, i got it already, whether see log or not, i can't download success when i re-open the app, However, when I exit to the background and switch back directly, before download successed.